# Counting the number of different 5 characters substrings inside a string

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a string i want to count how many substrings with len = 5 i have on it.

For example: Input: "ABCDEFG" Output: 3

And I'm not sure what should be the easiest and fast way to do this in python. Any idea?

**Update:**

I want only to count different substrings.

Input: "AAAAAA"
Substrings: 2 times "AAAAA"
Output: 1

Comment: What are the three substrings that you identify?

Comment: This looks like a job for N-GRAMs :) Well I guess I'm assuming you want the substring combinations, if you just want to count them then simple math works

Comment: In my example the 3 substrings are "ABCDE", "BCDEF" and "CDEFG".
This is not a anagram.

Comment: [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) are not [anagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram)

Comment: That update makes this question much more interesting :) I wonder what ends up being the most efficient approach.

Comment: I took a stab at combining my answer with a Counter (but I fear if this was a python interview question I might not pass)

Comment: Well, I enjoyed golfing with you guys... :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for s in 'ABCDEF', 'AAAAAA':
...     len({s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s)-n+1)})
... 
2
1
```

Comment: Your solution took just 2.37 seconds in a 14846650 len string. The best yet. Thanks o/

Comment: Now that is the kind of answer that kicks butt in a Python interview. Let me see if I can unpack it. The outer loop is just to test the two examples. The inner statement is using {} to construct a set out of the output of that inner list comprehension. The list is constructed by walking over the string and pulling out n elements starting at 0 and going until it reaches the len() - n. By constructing the set you always end up with unique elements. Smart approach :)

Comment: @JasonSperske: It is a generator expression, not a list comprehension i.e., it should be equivalent to: `S = set()` `for i in range(len(s)-n+1): S.add(s[i:i+n])` -- there is no reason to create an intermediate list here.

Answer (score 2):

To get the sub strings you could use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) like this:

```
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> for gram in ngrams("ABCDEFG", 5):
...     print gram
... 
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
('C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G')
```

You could apply a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then get the unique n-grams (and their frequency) like so:

```
>>> Counter(ngrams("AAAAAAA", 5))
Counter({('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'): 3})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension *(code golf)*:

```
findSubs=lambda s,v:[''.join([s[i+j] for j in range(v)]) for i,x in enumerate(s) if i<=len(s)-v]
findCount=lambda s,v:len(findSubs(s,v))

print findSubs('ABCDEFG', 5)  #returns ['ABCDE', 'BCDEF', 'CDEFG']
print findCount('ABCDEFG', 5) #returns 3
```

---

***Update***

For your update, you could cast the list above to a set, back to a list, then sort the strings.

```
findUnique=lambda s,v:sorted(list(set(findSubs(s,v))))
findUniqueCount=lambda s,v:len(findUnique(s,v))

print findUnique('AAAAAA', 5)      #returns ['AAAAA']
print findUniqueCount('AAAAAA', 5) #returns 1
```

Comment: I like your approach, it uses Python built-ins and I would assume it has the same performance as mine.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the length minus 4:

```
def substrings(s):
    return len(s) - 4
```

This is true since you can create a substring for the first, second, ..., fifth-to last character as the first letter of the substring.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution may be:

```
def count(string, nletters):
  return max(0, len(string) - nletters + 1)
```

Which has the use case as per your example:

```
print count("ABCDEFG", 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> how_much = lambda string, length: max(len(string) - length + 1, 0)
>>> how_much("ABCDEFG", 5)
3
```

Comment: "*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*", [PEP20](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). The obvious way to create a named function is `def`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure python is not a good language to do this in, but if the length of distinct substrings you want to find is not small like 5 but larger like 1000 where your main string is very long, then a linear time solution to your problem is to build a suffix tree, you can read about them online. A suffix tree for a string of length n can be built in O(n) time, and traversing the tree also takes O(n) time and by traversing the higher levels of the tree you can count all distinct substrings of a particular length, also in O(n) time regardless of the length of substrings you want.